# cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'group' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

**I need to create XML from this XSD:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="group">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="person" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="20" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Here is the XML I've tried:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<group name="abcd">
    xmlns="www.example.org"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="ex1.xsd">
    <person>Joao</person>
    <person>Andre</person>
    <person>Filipe</person>
    <person>Joaquim</person>
    <person>Rui</person>
</group>
```

**I am getting this error:**

> Not valid.
>   Error - Line 10, 9: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'group' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Comment: You are closing the `<group>` before the namespace declarations. You can see it nicely here with the code coloring.

Comment: well i had it closed at end of ex1.xsd before and it says that it is not valid xml element type group must be followed with > or />

Comment: The opening `group`will be closed after the second namespace. Trust me, as it is now, it is not even valid Xml without any schema validating it.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You would have a dangling `>` in your Xml: `...="ex1.xsd">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of issues:

- As Filburt mentioned, you've prematurely closed the opening `group`
  tag.  This is the direct cause of your immediate error.  It causes
  the parser to misinterpret what you intend to be attributes as text
  content to the `group` element.
- `schemaLocation` must take namespace-XSD *pairs*.
- `elementFormDefault="qualified"`
- etc.

Altogether, the following XSD will validate the following XML successfully.

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="group">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="person" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="20" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<group name="abcd"
       xmlns="http://www.example.org"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org ex1.xsd">
  <person>Joao</person>
  <person>Andre</person>
  <person>Filipe</person>
  <person>Joaquim</person>
  <person>Rui</person>
</group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the 'group' definition in XSD to include mixed="true"

```
<xs:element name="group">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
```

Comment: This helped me when XMLs with random indentation failed against schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I copied a code from Skype which inserted weird encoding. The solution was to remove the pasted code and rewrite all wrong encoded part by hand, without any pasted encoded characters.